# expo init showing Error in downloading and expracting due to TypeError

Tags: node.js, react-native, ubuntu, npm, expo

I installed expo-cli in ubuntu using `npm install --global expo-cli` and it installed with some warning.

```bash
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.9.8: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@3.0.0: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead

added 1474 packages, and audited 1475 packages in 15s

121 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

26 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 17 high, 3 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Then I tried to create a new project using `expo init newapp` with blank template. But it failed and showing an error log given below

```bash
✔ Choose a template: › blank               a minimal app as clean as an empty canvas
Error downloading and extracting template package: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')
✖ Something went wrong while downloading and extracting the template.

Can't read JSON file: /home/ntpl/Documents/tutorial/native/newapp/app.json
└─ Cause: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ntpl/Documents/tutorial/native/newapp/app.json'
    ├─ readAsync /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/json-file/src/JsonFile.ts:158:13
    ├─ extractAndPrepareTemplateAppAsync /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/utils/extractTemplateAppAsync.ts:25:25
    └─ actionAsync /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/initAsync.ts:287:19
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

npm cache clean --force
npm fund
npm audit fix --force
npm i --package-lock-only
npm audit fix --force